# Try to change border-color of unselect object in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to jquery. Now I'm trying to change those unselected objects into red border to warn the user to fill in some values.

```
if($("select:visible").val()==undefined ){

            $(this).css({"border-color":"red"});
  }
```

but it doesn't seem to change anything. I want to change "those" if if statement is true. how can i implement it?

Also, Im trying to make the border red. But I don't want to just make it red. Instead I want the effect just like the bootstrap "input" with that blue border when "onfocus". Is it possible to do so?

```
$('#broadcast_next').click(function(){
        var mySelect = $("select:visible");
        if($("select:visible").val()=="" || $("input:visible").val()=="" ){

                $("select:visible").filter(function() { return this.value === "" }).addClass("invalid");

                $("input:visible").filter(function() { return this.value === "" }).addClass("invalid");


            alert('Please fill in the Blank');
        }

        else if(formpage_broadcast == 0){
            $('.page_basic').hide();
            if(eth_input==true){
                $('.page_ip').show();
                $('#broadcast_title').text('IP Configuration')
                formpage_broadcast++;
            }
            else{
                $('.page_rf').show();
                $('#broadcast_title').text('RF Configuration')
                formpage_broadcast++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: `this` isn't what you seem to think it is.

Comment: I know. im thinking bout "those" but there is no such thing in jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` isn't set per block, it's set per function, so `$(this)` doesn't select the element just referenced in the `if` condition. Keep a reference to the element instead:

```
var mySelect = $("select:visible");
if (mySelect.val() == undefined) {
  mySelect.css({"border-color":"red"});
}
```

Except that the above assumes there will be only one element. The following technique will handle any number of elements:

```
$("select:visible")
  .css({"border-color":""})                         // remove border from all
  .filter(function() { return this.value === "" })  // select empty ones
  .css({"border-color":"red"});                     // add border
```

Note that that uses `this`, but inside the function passed to `.filter()`. So what it does is first grab all visible select elements, then reduce that set to the ones with no value, then set those ones to have a red border.

You'd be better off adding and removing a class though, so that you can apply whatever additional formatting you like without having it all hard-coded inside your JS.:

```
$("select:visible")
  .removeClass("invalid")
  .filter(function() { return this.value === "" })
  .addClass("invalid");
```

Here's a small demo:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("select:visible")
    .removeClass("invalid")
    .filter(function() { return this.value === "" })
    .addClass("invalid");
});
```

```css
select {
  border-color: blue;
}
.invalid {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option value="">Please select a value</option>
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
<select>
<option value="">Please select a value</option>
<option value="1">Whatever</option>
<option value="2">Blah</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<button>Test Validation</button>
```

Comment: thanks, i guess that is what i need. also, is it possible to not just make the border red? like i want to make it like the bootstrap input effect. that blue with little gradient. is it possible?

Comment: I don't know which effect you're talking about, but as per my edited answer you really should be applying formatting by adding a class to the relevant fields rather than directly setting CSS properties from JS. That way you can add whatever additional formatting you like, including whatever it takes to get the gradient effect you're talking about.

Comment: i guess i just know how to do it. your answer is very helpful. thanks!

Comment: sorry man. there is still some problem with my code. in my code i still need to check if there existing any unselected item if not then go to next page. so still need a if statement in the jquery code. but i find that if i do so. it only check the first "<select>" if the first item do select it goes to next page. but problem is there may be some items that are not selected yet.

Comment: i updated my code on the problem statement. can you give me some suggestion? thanks a lot man.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you can't use `if($("select:visible").val()==""))` because that only tests the first select. Use the code from the end of my answer (and in my demo) to add the appropriate classes - make sure you include the `.removeClass()` part, that for some reason isn't in your question update - and then after that test if any elements have the `invalid` class: `if ($(".invalid").length>0) { alert("Error message here"); } else { /* success here */ }`.